# Reading a row with a NULL column causes an exception in slick

Tags: mysql, exception, slick

I have a table with a column type date. This column accepts null values,
therefore, I declared it as an Option (see field perDate below). When I
run the select query through the application code I get the following exception

slick.SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column

problem.This
is the Slick table definition:

```
  import java.sql.Date
  import java.time.LocalDate

  class FormulaDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Formula](tag, "formulas") {

    def sk = column[Int]("sk", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def formula = column[Option[String]]("formula")
    def notes = column[Option[String]]("notes")
    def periodicity = column[Int]("periodicity")
    def perDate = column[Option[LocalDate]]("per_date")(localDateColumnType)

    def * =
    (sk, name, descrip, formula, notes, periodicity, perDate) <>
    ((Formula.apply _).tupled, Formula.unapply)

    implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Option[LocalDate], Date](
    {
       case Some(localDate) => Date.valueOf(localDate)
       case None => null
    }, { sqlDate =>
       if (sqlDate != null) Some(sqlDate.toLocalDate) else None
   }
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapped column function just needs to provide the `LocalDate` to `Date` conversion. Slick will automatically handle `Option[LocalDate]` if it knows how to handle `LocalDate`.

That means changing your `localDateColumnType` to be:

```
implicit val localDateColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[LocalDate, Date](
  Date.valueOf(_), _.toLocalDate
)
```

Chapter 5 of [Essential Slick](https://underscore.io/books/essential-slick/) covers some of this, as does the section on [User Defined Features in the Manual](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/userdefined.html#scalar-types).

I'm not 100% sure why you're seeing the run-time error: my guess is that the column is being treated as an `Option[Option[LocalDate]]` or similar, and there's a level of null in there that's being missed.

BTW, your `def *` can probably be:

```
def * = (sk, name, descrip, formula, notes, periodicity, perDate).mapTo[Formula]
```

...which is a little nicer to read. The `mapTo` was added in Slick 3 at some point.